# Selenium can't find element of a link

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make a program which logs into my depop (A second-hand clothing selling app) and searches for a user. I've managed to make it log in so far. However, it can't find the element of the search button.

I've tried multiple didn't methods but none have worked. Keep in  mind I have started learning this today so I am a beginner.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #allows keyboard to be used
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By #allow waiting
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as cond
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def search():
    driver.implicitly_wait(4)
    searchbox = driver.find_element_by_name('a')
```

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

I just get variations of this error message depending on how I do it.

EDIT:
The element is :

```
a
< span > Search < /span >
/a
```

EDIT 2: TO add some more detail onto this to make it easier to understand, when I click on the button, it makes a pull down menu of the actual search bar. So if it eventually finds the element. It gives me this "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Comment: Can you add the HTML code for the element you are trying to find?

Comment: find_element_by_name will find the element according to the 'name' attribute.  (Right now you are looking for an element with the attribute: name="a"...)

Comment: I've added what I think is the HTML code. I've just put spaces in between the span and the ">" symbols or else they wouldn't be picked up. If I try to find the element using Xpath. It still can't find it. E.g searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount"]/div/div/div[7]/div[1]')

Comment: Instead of the hand crafted HTML update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Comment: 1. Check in yoru HTML if these elements are present in a iframe. If so, you may have to switch to that iframe and then find the element.
2. If you are getting stale element exception, you have to refresh your driver object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`find_element_by_name` function](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_name) locates a [WebElement](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement) by its [`name` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp), in your case neither [span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) nor [a tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) have the `name`.

So you either need to go for `find_element_by_tag_name` attribute:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
```

but be aware that it will return the first link from the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), if you need to match the link having inner span with `Search` text you will need to go for [XPath locator](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Search')]/parent::a")
```

It would be also good to wrap your locator into an [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Answer (score 0):

`a` is not a name and hence it would not result in finding an element by using method `find_element_by_name`. Please try using xpath `//span[text()='Search']`  to find the element search. Please check(in developer console or some other browser extension like xpath, chropath etc) how many elements are being returned using this xpath. If there is just one element, you are good to go. Else, find some other strategy to reach to the desired element before proceeding with performing actions on it.